# How to transfer files using WinSCP console from a remote Windows 8 Server to a Linux server?

Tags: linux, windows, scp, winscp

I am currently connected to a windows server. I installed winscp on it. I run the winscp and connect to a linux server. Now on the GUI of the winscp, i clicked the console, and use the scp command. The file on the remote server is `C:\xampp\htdocs\android\files\file.txt` now I want to transfer it to my linux server. I'm planning to automate this using an application created in python. But the problem is my code is incorrect. To be honest I don't really get it. So please guide me.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
scp C:\xampp\htdocs\android\files\file.txt remote_server_ip_add@linux_ip_add:/home
```

I don't know if this is correct. It's just not working.

The user name of the remote server for example is `remote_server`. And the user name of the linux server for example is `linux_server`.

Should it be like this?

```
scp C:\xampp\htdocs\android\files\file.txt remote_server@linux_server:/home
```

I also got this error:

```
C: node name or service name not known
```

Comment: Btw, to me it looks like that the fact the Windows 8 server is "remote" is bit irrelevant to the topic (how are you "connected"? RDP?), you are just making your question confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer to the [Console window of WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_console), you need to realize that the command executes on the remote server. While your `scp` syntax might work, if you had executed the command on a local machine (had you have the `scp` command there).

What do you want to achieve? Why are you trying to transfer file using command line, if you are in a GUI client?

Were you just testing, so that you can use the command for automation? Note that WinSCP has the [`put` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put) to upload files. But you cannot issue scripting commands in GUI, you need to do it in a [scripting mode](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting). For more details see the [Guide to automate file transfers to FTP server or SFTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

Comment: yes you're right im going to use the command for automation sir, sorry i can't upvote you because of lack of reputation.

Answer (score -1):

It should be `user_name@server_ip:filename`. (Run `scp` without arguments to see info)

```
scp C:\xampp\htdocs\android\files\file.txt linux_Server@linux_ip_add:/home
```

---

BTW: Names are case sensitive - so `linux_Server` is not the same as `linux_server` , etc.